# How to download and install a macOS on a MacBook whose hard drive was changed

Tags: macos

I need to install the latest version of macOS available for my 2010 MacBook Pro. I believe this would be macOS High Sierra. The Mac currently has a recently purchased new hard drive that is completely empty and without an operating system. I do not have a OS X installation DVD or bootable flash installer with the either OS X or macOS. I tried to download macOS High Sierra, but as soon as the download hit 4.0GB, it would stop and give the error message "Invalid link." If someone could provide a link and demonstrate how to download and install the macOS to fix my problems, that would be greatly appreciated. Any other advice would also be greatly appreciated.

I have the following addition machines and operating systems available:

- I have been able to install Linux Ubuntu on this Mac.
- I do have access to a laptop with Windows 10 Pro.

> Note: Due to the Mac's inability to connect to the internet and lack of an operating system, I am unable to even attempt "macOS Recovery over the internet."

Comment: Some 2010 Macs can use [macOS Recovery over the internet](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904) to install OS X or macOS. Otherwise, do you have access to another Mac or PC? If so, which operating system version is installed?

Comment: For now what I installed in the MacBook is Linux Ubuntu but I wasn't to change it back to macOS but it doesn't seem to be possible because I can't download macOs High Sierra DMG file

Comment: Which Linux Ubuntu? Also, are you sure you do not have access to another computer with Windows, OS X or macOS installed? If so, which operating system version is installed? I ask because there are already answers posted which can use Windows, OS X and/or macOS to install High Sierra on your Mac. Also, did you try  [macOS Recovery over the internet](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904)?

Comment: I have access to a laptop with Windows 10 Pro, but I don't think it will be of any assistance to me because, as I previously mentioned, I recently purchased a new hard drive that is completely empty and without an operating system. Nevertheless, I tried to download macOS High Sierra, but as soon as the download hit 4.0Gb, it would stop and give the error message "Invalid link." Due to the MacBook's inability to connect to the internet and lack of an operating system, I am unable to even attempt "macOS Recovery over the internet."